# Как работает функция fork() в C. Не могу понять результат работы программы

Tags: c, процесс

У меня есть вот такой короткий пример кода, нам его дали что бы продемонстрировать работу функции fork():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
int main () {

pid_t pid;
pid = fork();
pid = fork();

printf("Fork-Test\n");

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Мне не совсем понятен результат.
В итоге у меня 4 раза в терминале пишет Fork-Test
Не понимаю, во-первых почему это происходит больше одного раза, ведь я вызваю метод `printf("Fork-Test\n");` только один раз, во-вторых, раз уже несколько раз, то почему именно 4? При чем еще и в следующем виде:

```
Fork-Test
Fork-Test

Process returned 0 (0x0) execution time : 0.007 s
Press ENTER to continue 
Fork-Test
Fork-Test
```

смысл мне не понятен.
буду благодарна за любые пояснения по поводу `fork()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Процесс после [системного вызова `fork`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=fork&category=2), **раздваивается**, у исходного процесса создаётся идентичный потомок-двойник в идентичном состоянии (ну почти). **Создавшийся процесс будет занят выполнением того же кода ровно с той же точки, что и исходный процесс.**

Различить кто создал, а кто создался, можно по возвращаемому значению `fork`, поэтому его результат обычно передаётся в `if`, чтобы эти процессы выполнили какие-то разные вещи, один пошёл в ветку `if`, другой в ветку `else`.

Вы же возвращаемое значение игнорируете (сохраняете, но никак не используете), и потому оба процесса продолжают идти по одному и тому же пути. И натыкаются на ещё один вызов `fork`. **И каждый из них раздваивается снова**. Получается следующая картина:

```
     P               # перед первым pid = fork();

  [fork 1]

     P               # перед вторым pid = fork();
      \
       P(1)          # перед вторым pid = fork();

  [fork 2]

     P               # перед printf("Fork-Test\n");
    / \
P(2)   P(1)          # перед printf("Fork-Test\n");   # перед printf("Fork-Test\n");
           \
            P(1)(2)  # перед printf("Fork-Test\n");
```

После второго форка процессов уже 4. И после этих форков **каждый** процесс доходит до вызова `printf` и выводит указанную строку. **Каждый процесс делает это сам.** Поэтому вывод происходит столько раз, сколько вышло процессов.

Можете убедиться в этом, поместив вывод перед вторым форком (вывод произойдёт дважды) или перед первым (единожды).

Завершаются они независимо друг от друга.
У вас получилось, что процесс `P` завершился вторым. А нечто, через что вы запускали этот процесс, следило только за процессом `P`, но не его "клонами" (т. к. у них собственные `pid`, process ID), поэтому для остальных такого вывода нет.

Comment: какая-то диаграмма совсем непонятная получилась

Comment: @Grundy Главное понять, что они плодятся методом вегетативного размножения.:)

Answer (score 11):

Трудность понимания `fork` состоит в том, что все запускаемые процессы имеют дело с одним и тем же вами написанным кодом.

Когда вы вызвали `fork` первый раз

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
int main () {

pid_t pid;
pid = fork();

// после первого вызова fork

pid = fork();

printf("Fork-Test\n");

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

То та часть вашей программы, которая расположена после комментария, выполняется уже двумя процессами. Правда, каждый из процессов имеет свое адресное пространство. Вы можете представить это следующим образом

```
Родительский процесс         Дочерний процесс
====================         ================ 

pid = fork();                pid = fork();

printf("Fork-Test\n");       printf("Fork-Test\n");

return EXIT_SUCCESS;         return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}                            }
```

Теперь каждый из процессов встречает на своем пути следующий вызов `fork`. Поэтому появляется еще два процесса. И все четыре процесса выполняют каждый в своем адресном пространстве предложения

```
printf("Fork-Test\n");

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

В документации в описании `fork` написано

```
fork() creates a new process by duplicating the calling process.  The
       new process is referred to as the child process.  The calling process
       is referred to as the parent process.

       The child process and the parent process run in separate memory
       spaces.  **At the time of fork() both memory spaces have the same
       content.**
```

Обратите внимание на последнее предложение из цитаты. Это означают, что каждый процесс имеет, грубо говоря, тот же самый исходный код вашей программы, выполнение которого для нового процесса начинается после предложения с вызовом `fork` .